# PHP don't use temp file for upload

Tags: php, upload, embedded, temp

I'm working on an embedded system that doesn't have much space so I would like to bypass creating a temp file on upload or just keep the temp file as the real file.

I'm creating a way to update the system by uploading a file via the web. My concern is that the system takes up ~50% of the space and an update can take up to ~40% of the space available. With that said, there's not enough space to store the temp file along with the real file while its copying. Is there a way to make not use a temp file and just create the real file from the start? If not, is there a way to make PHP not delete the uploaded temp file so I can just use that?

Comment: Get more space, thats all you can do.

Comment: PHP's upload internal upload handling is crap. If you don't want to write to a temp file, then use a different language to handle the uploads.